# Initialization of a wchar_t array with wmemset. Does encoding matter?

Tags: c++, wchar-t

How do I correctly initialize a wchar_t array with wmemset? 
Should I use '\0' or L'\0' ? Does it matter? 
does the encoding matter ? (unicode, ISO####)

eg

```
wchar_t arr[20];
wmemset(arr, '\0', sizeof(arr));
```

Comment: Hadn't heard of `wmemset` before. Looking at the documentation, the third parameter is the number of characters not bytes so using `sizeof` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `L''` form to get a `wchar_t` type, although any value that fits within a `char` (such as `'\0'`) will be automatically converted using the usual integer promotions. See [character literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) or [C++ Character Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx).

It's unclear to me what code page the source will be interpreted in. To be safe, it's best to use a `L'\u20ac'` or `L'\U000020ac'` form to specify characters outside of the ASCII character set.

Comment: thanks for your answer, to help me clarify, I am talking about specifically wmemset, your anwers refer to that?

you say that the trailing zero will be the same with `'\0'` and `L'\0'` ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. The parameter to `wmemset` is a `wchar_t`, and if you give a `char` instead it will be promoted so the result is the same.